# How to handle data in multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call multiple ajax call in a loop.

I've to store the ajax call request data after finishing each request.

In my case, it stores final request data in all the responses.

This is my code

```
for (var postdata in response) {
    postdata1 = JSON.stringify(response[postdata]);
    var part1 = "<div class='col-md-4'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='";
    var part2 = "' alt='Visualize Image' style='width:100%'> <div class='caption'><a href='#' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data='" + postdata1 + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span> Like </a></div></div></div>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: postdata1,

        success: function (dataString) {

            $(".loader").css('display', 'none');

            var source = 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataString;

            console.log(postdata);

            $(".row").append(part1 + source + part2);

        }

    });
}
```

How do I store each postdata1 value in its respective response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by- "How do I store each postdata1 value in its respective response?" There's only one response variable that is not getting changed at all.

Comment: I wanted to store request input[postdata1]  with the response data.

Comment: In that case, the answer below by @Sniper Wolf is correct

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand what do you want to save, but maybe you can create an array *before* the loop and pushing the data inside in jQuery ajax `success` routine like that:

```
var ajaxResults = [];
for (var postdata in response) {
    postdata1 = JSON.stringify(response[postdata]);

    // ...

    $.ajax({
        // ...

        success: function (dataString) {
            // ...
            ajaxResults.push({
                "postdata1": postdata1,
                "dataString": dataString
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Be careful about asynchronous events. I suggest you to trigger an event at the end of the *last* ajax call in order to be sure that `ajaxResults` is consistent and complete.

You may accept this answer if you believe that is a solution to your problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you can read how :)